# How to reset an unordered index to an ordered one in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like below

textdata

```
   id   user_category   operator   circle  
0  23       1           vodafone   mumbai  
1  45       2           airtel     andhra  
2  65       3           airtel     chennai  
3  23       6           vodafone   mumbai  
4  45       1           airtel     gurgaon  
5  65       3           airtel     ongole  
6  23       4           vodafone   mumbai  
7  45       1           airtel     telangana  
8  65       3           airtel     chennai
```

In my data 1,2,4,6 in user category is transactional and 3 in user_category is promotional data.So i have divided that by using the following commands

```
transactional = textdata[textdata['user_category'].isin([1,2,4,6])]
promotional = textdata[textdata['user_category'].isin([1])]
```

so i got the output for transactional and promotional like below

transactional

```
   id   user_category   operator   circle  
0  23       1           vodafone   mumbai  
1  45       2           airtel     andhra      
3  23       6           vodafone   mumbai  
4  45       1           airtel     gurgaon  
6  23       4           vodafone   mumbai  
7  45       1           airtel     telangana
```

promotional

```
    id   user_category   operator   circle 
 2  65       3           airtel     chennai  
 8  65       3           airtel     chennai 
 5  65       3           airtel     ongole
```

but what i am expecting is to order the index
Expected output:

transactional

```
   id   user_category   operator   circle  
0  23       1           vodafone   mumbai  
1  45       2           airtel     andhra      
2  23       6           vodafone   mumbai  
3  45       1           airtel     gurgaon  
4  23       4           vodafone   mumbai  
5  45       1           airtel     telangana
```

promotional

```
    id   user_category   operator   circle 
 1  65       3           airtel     chennai  
 2  65       3           airtel     chennai 
 3  65       3           airtel     ongole
```

this is how i tried for that

transactional.reset_index(inplace = True)

And this is how i got

transactional

```
    index  id   user_category   operator   circle  
 0    0    23       1           vodafone   mumbai  
 1    1    45       2           airtel     andhra      
 2    3    23       6           vodafone   mumbai  
 3    4    45       1           airtel     gurgaon  
 4    6    23       4           vodafone   mumbai  
 5    7    45       1           airtel     telangana
```

But i am expecting in the following way

transactional

```
   id   user_category   operator   circle  
0  23       1           vodafone   mumbai  
1  45       2           airtel     andhra      
2  23       6           vodafone   mumbai  
3  45       1           airtel     gurgaon  
4  23       4           vodafone   mumbai  
5  45       1           airtel     telangana
```

Please help me how can i do this.

But don't suggest me like this way

```
del transactional['index']
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `drop=True` option of [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html).

> drop : boolean, default False.
>   Do not try to insert index into dataframe columns. This resets the index to the default integer index

So, instead of calling:

```
transactional.reset_index(inplace = True)
```

Do:

```
transactional.reset_index(inplace = True, drop=True)
```

Comment: can you tell me in detail .what i mean is can you include your code in reset_index command